# how can search data on multiple field on mongoDB with C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am using MongoDB with C# Driver
I try to fetch data based on search as an `like` from collection using following code:

```
col.Find(new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("Name", new BsonRegularExpression(search)))).ToList();
```

it's work for single field data search but how can do with this multiple field.

Comment: Did you check the tutorial on the official MongoDB page? https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/query/

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for  ```col.Find(new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("Name", new BsonRegularExpression("test")), new BsonElement("Moar", new BsonRegularExpression("test")), new BsonElement("Fields", new BsonRegularExpression("test")))).ToList();``` Still not recommending it though...

Comment: `col.Find(new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("Name", new BsonRegularExpression("test")), new BsonElement("Moar", new BsonRegularExpression("test")), new BsonElement("Fields", new BsonRegularExpression("test")))).ToList();` it's not working always returning null list. i did't know which type match `and\or`